# Pivot table column based on running total values

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have the following pivot table set up:

[image]

I then have both the **Contract Value** and **Earned Cash** columns shown as a running total on the **Period** column, which changes it to this:

[image]

What I'd like to do is add a third column that shows the **Earned Cash** as a percentage of **Contract Value** per **Period**, *using the values now shown in the running totals* (i.e. the values shown in the second screenshot above rather than the underlying ones before the running totals were applied as shown in the first screenshot above).

If I was doing this outside of a pivot table the end result would look something like this:

[image]

I'd also like to add a forth column that shows the **Earned Cash** as a percentage of the grand total of **Contract Value**.

Again, if I was doing this outside of a pivot table the end result would look something like this:

[image]

Everything I've tried so far seems to not be able to work with the running totals values as its base. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: @ Matt, what about adding 2 non pivot columns to to the right of your pivot table? it will be updated dynamically once you will refresh the pivot.

Comment: @Balinti thanks, I may try that if there's no way to do it within the pivot table itself, however things could get a bit messy if using a filter (rows from the pivot table would disappear, while non-pivot table columns would always show the same amount of rows).

Comment: You can try a Calculated Field in the pivot table. Click on the pivot table, go to Options > Fields, Items,  Sets > Calculated Field. Then type in the formula you need (in this case, = 'Earned Cash' / 'Contract Value'

Comment: Scratch that... it doesn't seem to work with running totals. It would probably work if you added columns in your data for YTD contract value and YTD earned.

Comment: If you want it in your pivot table, you could do the calc within the base data, and then pull it in as a column of the pivot.